# Emacs change window fringes (vertical padding)?

Tags: init-file, frames, fringe

I have Emacs 24 running in Linux Mint 18 Xfce.  As shown in the picture below by the red arrows, how can I decrease the width of the gray zones that are to the left/right of each Emacs window? The so-called "padding", I guess.

[image]

Comment: I recommend editing your question so that it's just a single question; when multiple unrelated questions get bundled together it's much harder for others find them later.

Comment: I removed the second question. Feel free to post it separately. (And consider editing, to replace the screenshot with one that doesn't include the web-browser part.)

Answer (score 2):

That's called the fringe. You can indeed turn it off or control it's size; see the documentation for the `fringe-mode` function (type `C-h f fringe-mode RET`).

Answer (score 1):

Just turn off both the left and right *fringe* (the vertical gray bars you noticed).

1. One way: `M-x customize-option default-frame-alist`, and add these entries, then save.

   ```
   INS DEL Parameter: left-fringe
              Value: 0
   INS DEL Parameter: right-fringe
              Value: 0
   ```

   That adds these entries to the alist value of **`default-frame-alist`**:

   ```
   (left-fringe . 0)

   (right-fringe . 0)
   ```

   So for example, if the original value of your `default-frame-alist` option was `nil` (aka `()`) then the new value after customization would be this:

   ```
   ((left-fringe . 0) (right-fringe . 0))
   ```

   `C-h v default-frame-alist` shows you the current value and describes this option.
2. Another way: customize option **`fringe-mode`**, setting it to `(0 . 0)`.

(I mention option `default-frame-alist` first because it is a good thing to know. It lets you configure many other frame parameters, besides just the fringe.)

For more information, see the Emacs manual, node [Fringes](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Fringes.html).  You can find this node yourself, by *asking Emacs* about the fringe: **`C-h r`**, then **`i fringe TAB`**.